# contract inline assembly - return array parts by using assembly

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I've a couple of questions.

1. mload function returns the data that resides on the address we pass to mload. Is this correct ?
2. add function is used to give us the address from 0 to whatever we pass. add(arr, 64) would return the address from arr + 64 bytes. correct. ?
3. I want to achieve same things with storage variables (x_slot and x_offset).. I have the following code.

```js
uint[] storageArr;
    function assembly2() public view returns (uint a, uint b, uint c) {
        storageArr.push(111);
        storageArr.push(222);
        storageArr.push(333);
        
       
        assembly {
            a := sload(0)
            b := sload(32)
            c := sload(64)
        }
    }
```

This returns {3, 0, 0,}. The first one(slot) is 3, since it stores the length of the array. why is the second and third one 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to their unpredictable size, dynamically-sized array types use a Keccak-256 hash computation to find the starting position of the array data.

So in your example:

- The position of `storageArr[0]` is at `keccak256(uint256(0)) + 0`
- The position of `storageArr[1]` is at `keccak256(uint256(0)) + 1`
- The position of `storageArr[2]` is at `keccak256(uint256(0)) + 2`

Here is how you can put it into code:

```
function assembly2() public view returns (uint a, uint b, uint c) {
    uint index = uint(keccak256(abi.encode(uint(0))));
       
    assembly {
        a := sload(add(index, 0))
        b := sload(add(index, 1))
        c := sload(add(index, 2))
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I write that in assembly language ? if you could change the code to reflect it, that would be great

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: I think that `sload(keccak256(storageArr, n))` for `n` in `[0, 1, 2]` might work.

Comment: sload(keccak256(storageArr,0)) returns error: Only local variables are supported. To access storage variables, use the _slot and _offset suffixes.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: OK, give me a few minutes to see if I can find it.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: See updated answer. BTW, note that your `view` function changes a state variable. You should basically move that part out into a different function.

Comment: Got it. So, now, none of them returns the number 3 which is the length of the array. So length is stored without hashes, and the actual numbers of the array is stored on the hashes. I thought the first number of the array would come after the slot of where the length of the array resides.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: Yeah, you already know how to get the array length - it is stated in your question. I gave you an answer on how to get the actual 3 values. You can integrate that into whatever it is you want (for example, the length along with the first two values).

Comment: So, How to get "address to mapping" store variable in assembly ? `mapping (address => uint) counter` I guess, `msg.sender` equal to in assembly `caller()`.