# where does function variables get created?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

```
function element() public  returns (uint) {
  uint test = 20;
  return test;
}
```

Where would `test` variable be created ? in memory or stack ?

The funny thing is from testing assembly, I can see that it's not in memory. I am just curious why ?

This is what I found on the internet. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This description distinguishes between storage and non-storage.

It seems to be using 'memory' in order to refer to non-storage.

It's probably not the best choice of words, as the keyword `memory` is used in order to indicate that a given variable is allocated on the heap.

In other words, you have 3 data sections:

1. Storage, where consistent data is located
2. Stack, where non-consistent data of primitive types is located
3. Heap, where non-consistent data of non-primitive types is located

Where:

- 'consistent data' is data which remains valid after the execution is completed
- 'primitive type' is every variable type except for arrays and structures

The description that you've found simply refers to all non-consistent data, regardless of its actual type, as data which resides memory and not in storage.

---

**UPDATE:**

The decision of whether to allocate a variable on the stack or on the heap actually depends on whether that variable is of constant length (which is known during compilation) or not.

For example, the following variables are of constant length:

```
uint256[2] a;

Foo b;

// Where:
struct Foo {
    uint256 x;
    uint256[2] y;
}
```

While the following variables are of non-constant length:

```
uint256[] a;

Foo b;

// Where:
struct Foo {
    uint256 x;
    uint256[] y;
}
```

The usage of `memory` is required in order to tell the compiler that a given variable is **not** in storage, as the compiler assumes `storage` by default for certain types like arrays and structures.

Comment: You probably want to wait for some feedback from a few other members here, as I'm not 100% sure of how accurate my answer is.

Comment: You can also find more relevant information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33839154/7400903) that I just found.

Comment: Will read it all that very soon and give you my thoughts too here. Before that, if you have time, could you look at this ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87975/sload-assembly-with-struct-not-working-in-solidity

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: I already have. You've asked a similar question before that one, to which I gave you [an answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87924/16043). You should obviously use a similar technical solution (as the one that I gave you on that answer), since those two questions differ only by the fact that you are trying to reference a structure instead of an array. There's a section in the official documentation which explains how the slots are mapped in memory.

Comment: you say:  'primitive type' is every variable type except for arrays and structures. what about mappings and strings?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: There is no support for `mapping` anywhere other than storage, so this type is obviously not relevant here, as you can obviously not declare it in memory (neither stack nor heap). With regards to strings, I think that they too will reside on the heap, because they are not of constant size.

Comment: yes, strings won't reside on heap by default, compiler asks to specify storage or memory. but yes, you're right. it can be stored in memory too

Comment: What about this one ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87993/how-do-storage-and-memory-variable-work . Thanks  so much for all the answers

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: Please read my update to the answer, and I will refer to that last comment of yours separately.

Comment: You say the following: "The decision of whether to allocate a variable on the stack or on the heap actually depends on whether that variable is of constant length". But if I have uint[2] test; in a function, it still won't be put on stack, since compiler will still ask :"storage or memory". No option for stack. So it's not always about constant length

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: You've missed the point explained in the very last line of the answer.

Comment: I've added another question. Since only i get answers during specific time in a whole day, I gather all my questions in the previous day. here it is: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87994/why-mload0-returns-wrong-number