# why mload(0) returns wrong number?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

```
    int  x; // Storage slot #0
    mapping (uint => uint)  y; // Storage slot #1
    uint []  z; // Storage slot #2
  
    function element() public  returns (uint a, uint b, uint c) {
      z.push(45);
      assembly {
          c:=mload(0)
      }
      
    }
```

z array is stored in storage. Running the below code returns `c` as 2. If I remove `z.push(45)`, then `c` returns 0.

Why does it return 2 in case I have `z.push(45)`. `z` is in storage, so why is it related to 0th address of memory(heap) ? I know 0th address is scratch space for hashing methods in memory, but i am curious why solidity stored number 2 in memory(heap) after doing `z.push(45)`.

Comment: There are two differents operations `mload` reads from memory and `sload` from storage. I think for both you can read an 'invalid' position and they will return 0.

Comment: why does the above example return 2 ? that's the interesting one

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.2/internals/layout_in_memory.html) memory at address 0-64 is used as scratch pad for other operations so it is garbage.

Comment: yeah, i get that, but it's interesting why z.push(45) causes 2 to be put into that memory's address

Comment: You come from C, right? In C, that would be *undefined behavior* in both cases (with and without that `push` line), because you'd be trying to read from a memory address where no variable has been properly allocated.

Comment: So you're asking us to explain the behavior of your solc-generated output (the bytecode), when the input (your code) kinda violates the rules (which solc, just like many other compiler, is unfortunately unable to catch).

Comment: Yes, looks like 2 comes from nowhere or everywhere and we can't and shouldn't worry about it at all. I have another question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87995/why-do-i-have-to-specify-memory-in-arguments

Comment: The reason 2 is at memory address 0 is because to store something 45 in z it needs to calculate the slot used by z, which is keccak256(2)

Comment: @Ismael ah, that makes sense.