# why do i have to specify memory in arguments?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

My function body looks like this:

```js
function element(uint a, uint b, uint[2] memory c) public returns(uint e, uint f, uint g, uint k) {
```

I am wondering why do I put `memory` keyword before `c` ? I know that the argument parameters are stored in calldata. so by using `calldataload`, I successfully get `a` and `b` variables' values. The funny thing is by using `calldataload` , I also managed to get `c`(array) variable's first and second values.

So, turns out `c` is also in calldata location. Why do we specify `memory` then ?

Comment: No good reason AFAIK. The compiler assumes storage for every array and structure, unless `memory` is explicitly stated. Obviously, non of the function arguments can ever reside in storage, so this is clearly just a redundant limitation added by the authors of the compiler (probably made it easier on them to parse the code).

Comment: haha, so funny. Thanks @goodvibration . So it means it's still on calldata

Comment: NP, but keep in mind - AFAIK. Not all the memory-layout design and considerations are 100% clear to me either. I'm assuming that most of them follow the same pattern as C, with storage being (kind of) equivalent to data section in C (global and/or static variables), and non-storage being split into stack for variables of known length and heap for variables of unknown length.

Comment: sounds good. I want to make sure about something since you mentioned known length. in a function, uint[2] test can't be created unless i specify memory or storage. So array has known length, but still it won't be on stack. It seems like by known length, you mean primitive types. right ?

Comment: No, I actually mean *known length*. As I said, `memory` only tells the compiler that an array/struct is not in storage, as implicitly assumed by the compiler. I have also explained that at the end of my answer to one of your previous questions, which you seem to have overlooked (or ignored). However, at the beginning of that same answer, I did state that the distinguish (between stack and heap) is based on primitive/non-primitive type rather than on known/unknown length. I'm not sure which one it is, and to a certain extent, these two definitions overlap.

Comment: In either case, why do you even care whether it's on the stack or in the heap? Even the official documentation doesn't distinguish between the two, because it has zero impact on your coding, as well as on the behavior of your contract. In terms of memory considerations, all you really need to care about is storage vs non-storage. Both the stack and the heap fall under the category of non-storage (which is sometimes referred to as 'memory').

Comment: I agree ! It's just curiousity. If i don't understand something at some level, I hate coding then. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87998/why-does-this-contract-ask-to-increase-gas-limit

Comment: Your questions are well in place though. Solidity's memory design is most certainly not thoroughly explained in the official documentation.