# why does this contract ask to increase gas limit?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

```js
string test;
    function assemblyStorage() public payable returns (string memory a){
     test = "good";
     assembly {
         a:=sload(0)
     }
    }
```

I am trying to return the string which should be stored in the first slot alongside the length of the string as stated in the docs. But calling assemblyStorage function results : `increase gas limit` . Whatever I increase it too, it doesn't matter. What Really causes this error is the assembly code. no idea why.

Comment: It's not the contract asking that, it's your transaction execution, whose code you haven't provided here.

Comment: calling from `remix`. no need to provide any code since there are not any

Comment: You're missing `view`, to begin with. This makes your RPC into a transaction, which requires mining, and whose return-value is not visible off-chain (e.g., in remix). Second, you are attempting to write an integer into a string. Not so sure about the meaning of that in Solidity. The equivalent of that in C would be (yet again, when considering all your recent questions) *undefined behavior*. It's a little pointless to try and explain the result of UB code.

Comment: how am I trying to write an integer into a string ?

Comment: `a:=sload(0)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `a` ends up pointing to a very large memory address and that causes the EVM to run out of gas, since you need to pay for memory used.

The first storage slot was modified by this line

```
test = "good";
```

Since it is a "short" string (less than 31 bytes) it is stored in one slot in compact form (data at the right and length x 2 at the left).

```
0x676f6f6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
```

For more detail read the article [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 3 — The Hidden Costs of Arrays](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-the-hidden-costs-of-arrays-28e119f04a9b).

Then `a` is overwritten with the content of the first storage slot.

```
a := sload(0)
```

Now `a` is pointing to a very large address and that causes the out of gas error because solidity tries to read from it, and you need to pay gas for whole memory even if it wasn't assigned anything.

---

We can do safely for "short" string in assembly with

```
function assemblyStorage() public payable returns (string memory a){
    test = "good";
    assembly {
        let r := sload(0)
        // string length
        let l := shr(1, and(r, 0xff))
        // allocate memory for a
        a := mload(0x40)
        // update free memory pointer
        // a + 0x20 + 0x20 * trunc((l + 0x1f) / 0x20)
        mstore(0x40, add(a, add(0x20, shl(5, shr(5, add(l, 0x1f))))))
        // store length
        mstore(a, l)
        // copy data
        mstore(add(a, 0x20), and(r, not(0xff)))
    }
}
```

In this case using solidity directly is much easier and less error prone. It will work for any string.

```
function assemblyStorage() public payable returns (string memory a){
    test = "good";
    a = test;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer.  one note though, from your example: a:=sload(0) means that a would get equal to 0x676f6f6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008.  why doesn't the function then return `0x676f6f6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008` as string ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili In assembly `a` is a pointer you aren't modifying `a`'s content but its address. It fails when solidity tries to read from the pointer.

Comment: so in a nutshell, a is an address. if so, why doesn't it return address as a string ? it seems like after assembly, solidity tries to load from that address again. it's like load(sload(0)) where load function just loads data from sload(0) . makes sense ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili I didn't read the compiler source, I'd guess it is a sort of function epilogue, perhaps it is trying to copy all return data to one buffer the it will use for the RETURN opcode. Let's say the compiler is not very smart.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me. 0th slot contains `0x676f6f6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008`. I think when we do this `sload(0)`, solidity can't get the actual string , since it contains integer+string. and hence the error . don't you think ?

Comment: You say: `Then a is overwritten with the content of the first storage slot.`. So, the content of the first storage slot is `0x676f6f6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008`. So a should be getting directly `0x676f6f6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008`. but solidity can't convert from this to string , maybe that's why an error , who knows. is there a chance for this or you're sure it tries to load from slot 0th, and then tries to load again from whatever it got from 0th slot ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili EVM assembly is very simple it does what it is instructed to do, for example `a := 0x123412341234` will make a point to `0x123412341234`, it doesn't know that it isn't an memory address to the EVM it is just copying 32 bytes. If you want to modify the content pointed by a you have to use mstore, `mstore(a, 0x123412341234)`.

Comment: The question is if I type a:=5 , a becomes 5, if I type a:= 0x123412341234, why does it become a pointer? if I transform string into hex, the hex value could look like an address. so how would it differ if it should be a pointer or not .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113703/discussion-between-nika-kurashvili-and-ismael).