# store data in any slot

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
contract test  {

    bytes32 private constant ownerSlot = keccak256("ownerSlot");
    
    constructor(address _implementation) public {
        bytes32 s = ownerSlot;
        assembly {
          sstore(s, _implementation)
        }
    }

}
```

I saw this code in openZeppelin. I just removed lots of parts that don't matter for this question that I have..

so `s` variable in the constuctor will be `17d3e5a50a85cedc34e47ec97ca2e5dc1811e6f47a6d397255c987f7c733e0bd` because this is what the `keccak256` returns for the `ownerSlot`.

Question 1) As we know, storage slots start from 0. How is it possible that I can store something at `17d3e5a50a85cedc34e47ec97ca2e5dc1811e6f47a6d397255c987f7c733e0bd`th slot ?

Question 2) One of the answers from this `stackExchange`  told me that if you're using let's say 15th slot, and you didn't put anything in previous slots, you still have to pay for all those slots. Is this correct ? if so, since `17d3e5a50a85cedc34e47ec97ca2e5dc1811e6f47a6d397255c987f7c733e0bd` this number is so huge, paying for all previous slots is cruel. What's your opinion ?

Comment: My opinion is that you can write a simple test and measure the gas cost of that. I did, and the gas cost of it with `s` being set to that value in your question is the same as the gas cost of it with `s` being set to `0` (5k gas when `_implementation` is zero, and 20k gas when `_implementation` is non-zero). So for sure, the answer to the 2nd part of your question is - no, this is not correct.

Comment: To answer the 1st part of your question, one needs to avoid considering the storage memory layout in the "traditional" perception of it as being a contiguous block of memory addresses. Similarly, contract addresses do not imply anything about their "location" inside the blockchain, and it's not as if you need to preallocate these addresses or anything like that. Or if you will - the contract at address X does not come "right before" the contract at address X + 1.

Comment: About 2nd question, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87998/why-does-this-contract-ask-to-increase-gas-limit I know it from here. Look where it says:  `Now a is pointing to a very large address and that causes the out of gas error because solidity tries to read from it, and you need to pay gas for whole memory even if it wasn't assigned anything`

Comment: That answer is about `mstore`, not `sstore`.

Comment: and do you think for `mstore` , it's correct even before we test it ?

Comment: but how is it about `mstore` , i am not sure, it uses `ssload`

Comment: I didn't test `mstore`, because it is not what's being asked in your question (and obviously, it is very different from `sstore`, since it has nothing to do with storage slots).

Comment: @NikaKurashvili You are mixing two different things memory and storage. For memory you are charged for [0, p] where p is the highest pointer you used, for storage you are charged only for the storage slots you modified.

Comment: Which coincides well with my gas-measurement results above.

Comment: awesome , thanks to both of you. really appreciate it